# Simple number guessing game using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a number guessing game on JS for a web dev training I'm on. The problem is that it always prints the `keyInYNStrict` without giving an another chance for the user. Ignore the fact that the strings and variables are not in English. Basically I want the `keyInYNStrict` to only come after the `arvaus == arvattava` is true and the game has ended.

```
const minLuku = 1; 
const maxLuku = 30;
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
let arvaus, arvattava, arvaustenLkm
do {
    arvaus = readlineSync.question('Ajattelen numeroa 1 ja 30 välillä. Arvaapa vaan');
    arvaustenLkm = 1;
    arvattava = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLuku + 1 - minLuku)) + minLuku 
    kelvollinen = !isNaN(arvaus) && arvaus > 0 && arvaus < 31;
    if (!kelvollinen) {
        console.log('Elä viitsi! Laita nyt jokin oikea numero.');
    }
    else if (arvaus < arvattava){
        arvaustenLkm++;
        console.log('Kokeile suurempaa lukua.');
    } else if (arvaus > arvattava){
        arvaustenLkm++;
        console.log('Kokeile pienempää lukua.');
    } else if (arvaus == arvattava){
        console.log('Hienoa. arvasit oikein ' + arvaustenLkm + ' arvauksella.')
    } 

} while (readlineSync.keyInYNStrict('Haluatko arvata uudestaan?'))
```

Comment: Make that loop to ``while(true)` and after `console.log('Hienoa. arvasit oikein ' + arvaustenLkm + ' arvauksella.')` put `if(readlineSync.keyInYNStrict('Haluatko arvata uudestaan?')) { break }` That should do it if I got you right.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two while loops nested. The first is to repeat the guessing until the number has been found, the second to ask if the user wished to play again. This becomes clearer if you break a single game into a function, and then wrap "Play again?" around that function.

The following is untested. Notice I also pulled out the "Invalid guess" check to separate it from the game logic. I think that also improves readability, and allows for the option of checking for some other exit condition should the user wish to end early.

EDIT: As I'm thinking about it, there's another problem: Do you want to reset the hidden number each guess? That's probably not consistent with expectations. I've modified the code to reflect.

```
const minLuku = 1; // Lower bound
const maxLuku = 30; // Upper bound
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
let arvaus, arvattava, arvaustenLkm
do {
        // Number of guesses
        arvaustenLkm = 1; 

        //Target number
        arvattava = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLuku + 1 - minLuku)) + minLuku 
    do {
        // User's guess
        arvaus = readlineSync.question('Ajattelen numeroa 1 ja 30 välillä. Arvaapa vaan');

        // Bad guess test
        if (isNaN(arvaus) || arvaus < minLuku || arvaus > maxLuku) {
            console.log('Elä viitsi! Laita nyt jokin oikea numero.');
            continue;
        }

        if (arvaus < arvattava){
            arvaustenLkm++;
            console.log('Kokeile suurempaa lukua.');
        } else if (arvaus > arvattava){
            arvaustenLkm++;
            console.log('Kokeile pienempää lukua.');
        } else if (arvaus == arvattava){
            console.log('Hienoa. arvasit oikein ' + arvaustenLkm + ' arvauksella.')
        }
    } while (arvaus != arvattava)

} while (readlineSync.keyInYNStrict('Play again?'))
```

Comment: thank you very much. it works, but it doesn't count the tries for some reason. the variable for the amount of tries is arvaustenLkm.

Comment: @mntblnk, I'd made an edit to the code, as the original version was overwriting guesses (and the hidden number!) each iteration. Did you try the newest edit?